# How to recover a “poof” disappearing MS Word draft?

Tags: microsoft-word

Sometimes I'm a couple of pages into an MS Word draft and it just goes “poof”… Gone.

I think there is a secret place it goes to. Can it be recovered?

MS Word help is no help on this one. Where is it?

Yes I should have saved every 10 minutes and it may be keyboard related.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues--one is finding where drafts are saved, the other is determining why Word is doing that and fixing it.

As for the first issue, Word autosaves your work.  In many cases, you can recover it from within Word.  This [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/recover-unsaved-ms-word-2010-document-seconds/) explains several ways to get it back:

- Open up a new MS Word document. Go to File – Info – Manage Versions. Click on the little dropdown and select Recover Unsaved Documents.  While opening the recovered document, you can also make use of the Open & Repair feature for troubleshooting documents that might have gotten corrupted or damaged.
- You can browse to the following file locations to open the file manually, depending on your operating system:

  > Windows 7/Windows Vista: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\
  >
  > Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\ \Application Data\Microsoft\

The Auto Recover option kicks in if the document has been open for some period of time. You can easily change the Auto recover interval by going to File – Options – Save. The default is 10 minutes as indicated under – Save AutoRecover Information.